# Which flavor of Ubuntu is best for P4 without graphics card?

Tags: system-installation

I have an old computer with following configuration :

- 3.0 GHz Intel Pentium 4 processor
- 2GB DDR2 RAM
- 320 GB Hard Disk
- Without any Graphics card.

Which flavor of Ubuntu would be better suited for this configuration?

Comment: Are you sure there is no Graphics card of any kind, even built-in (do you plug your monitor in to anything?) some have assumed you want to access this computer without a screen (server setup).

Comment: How would you run a computer without a display? How would you want to display something without **any** kind of graphics card?
You have to at least have some inbuilt gc, otherwise you won't be able to configure the system properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should install a server version for a headless set-up. The newest version should run fine.

http://www.ubuntu.com/download/server

Comment: thanks but i also wish to know whether this server version needs graphics support or will work fine without graphics card.?

Comment: Headless = no graphics. Server version do not install any graphical stuff (you don't need those anyway).

Comment: If there is no graphics card it is sort of by definition a server. Where do you read he wants a desktop? There's no mention of that in the question. Also, please stop with the exclamation marks.

Comment: "without any graphics card" = no graphics card. I'm answering the question. You can disagree with me, but why not give your own answer, instead of all these comments that come across rather unpleasant? I'm not attacking your point of view, just giving mine. THat's what answers are for.

Answer (score 2):

Try using [xubuntu](http://www.xubuntu.org) or [lubuntu](http://www.lubuntu.org). They'll work pretty fine considering the amount of RAM you've got.

Comment: thanks for suggesstions.. i also want to know whether latest versions of xubuntoo need graphics card..?

Comment: I don't see the need to install any graphical system if you run a headless server?

Comment: Yes exactly. I dont need any high graphics. thats i want to confirm that these versions shouldn't bother me regarding graphic card..?

Comment: Assuming that your motherboard has a built-in video card xubuntu and lubuntu should work fine.